# Chrome Extension Get All Elements And Use Them

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tags, src

I'm here to ask how to get all the elements from the current chrome tab, and be able to use it like this (example: `document.getElementsByTagName("img");`). I already have the script that I'm going to use to get the images, and show them all, or download them, but it works only on the page, not in the tab. I'm making an "Image grabber/taker/chooser", and I need the user to be able to get all the pics form the current tab. I already have the code, but as I said, I need to get them from the tabs html code. I'm new to developing for chrome, so please don't get angry if I ask stupid things. Sorry for my bad english. Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if you want to use jquery or not, but here is a jquery example(this would be used in a content script):

```
var images = new Array();
$(img).each(function(){
images.push($(this).attr('src'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind using jquery. What do you mean "in the content script"? In the extension script? And if yes, will this get the images from the tab? I understand the code, (it gets the images and puts them in an array.) but I don't understand how it gets access to the tab. Thanks again.

Comment: look up content scripts on the dev pages, basically this code can be run on every page. The way you're doing it, I'm not sure how to.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me the following error: "img is not defined". I added the jquery lib, but it still gives me the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Did you include the jquery library as a content script?

Comment: Well I downloaded the lib and past it in the head of the html file --->    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>.

Comment: Do you have skype? I feel like I can help you out better on there.

Comment: Well I'm not home currently, and there is no skype installed here, and there's admin password, that I don't know. I have a skype on my phone, but it might be hard to communicate there. There it is:  ya-ivanov. with the dot in the end.